# VirtualBox lento con Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Tengo instalado Linux en VirtualBox en la compu con Windows 10. Cuestión que cuando uso VirtualBox va a paso de tortuga. No sé si es por qué estoy usando VirtualBox o lo tengo mal configurado

Comment: Revisa que recursos le asignaste a la maquina.

Comment: Que versión de Linux tienes instalada? Creo recordar que habia una que por muchos recursos que dedicaras la maquina iba fatal.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque parece un problema de superuser

Answer (score 3):

Lo más probable es que se deba a los recursos que destinas a esa máquina virtual (Windows 10 en tu caso). Cuando la máquina esta arrancada, se comparten los recursos de tu PC, con lo que un buen balanceo de estos es muy importante. 
De todos modos, si tu máquina no cuenta con los recursos necesarios quizás siempre te vaya algo mas lento cuando esté arrancada la máquina virtual.

Puedes darnos más detalle para saber mejor por donde puede ir el problema? RAM, HDD destinado,...?

Comment: En base memory tiene 3072MB (tengo max 6144) de procesador tengo 1CPU de 4 disponebles (no me deja editar) y Execution cap al 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente tu máquina virtual posea poca memoria RAM y tu procesador no sea muy bueno por lo que los recursos disponibles para ambas máquinas se hacen escasos.

En la BIOS de tu Equipo busca la opción Intel VT AMD VT o VT-X  y habilitala es la opcion de virtualizado de intel o amd en ocasiones por default no viene habilitado

Comment: Tengo en la compu un procesador Intel i3 con 6GB de RAM (en la compu no en virtualbox)

Comment: Entonces a la máquina no deberías meterle más de 3, y depende de las operaciones que hagas en la máquina igual requeriría algo más de procesador, tampoco tengo ,mucho más conocimiento sobre ello sorry

Answer (score 0):

Intenta  habilitar la aceleracion 3D y la memoria de video en La Maquina virtual y veamos que pasa, ademas me gustaria saber cuanta capacidad le diste a la maquina virtual Versiones de Ubuntu de la 13 en adelante ya consumen mas recursos si lo tuyo es instalar algo liviano te recomiento Lubuntu es muy bueno y corre con pocos recursos

Comment: Ya tiene activado el 3D, ;e do de base memory 3072MB (tengo max 6144) de procesador tengo 1CPU de 4 disponebles (no me deja editar) y Execution cap al 100%.